# run commands in UNIX server as root user using sshg3 or batch file

Tags: unix, ssh, sudo, openssh, san

I am using tectia tool for ssh. I am giving "sudo su -" command to become root user in the tool (it not asking for a password).

but , where iam trying to run the commands through batch file iam not able to become root user " iam getting user not allowed to run as root"

```
sshg3 -b user@host < c:\\file.bat
```

inside the file.bat

```
sudo su -
date
time
```

i want to run some commands as a root user using batch file , please anyone help in this

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant part of this batch file (including the specific sudo command) and the exact error message that you're getting. Don't paraphrase them.